# Are URLEncoder and URLDecoder not compatible?

Tags: java

I use 
`System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(URLEncoder.encode("й", "UTF-8"), "UTF-8"));`
and expecting to see "й" in output. But output filled with "?"... where is trouble?

Comment: What if you display `й` directly, does that show alright?

Comment: It must be a problem with your IDE, mine displays correctly. Do as Kayaman suggested, If you don't see the same, it's the problem with your IDE. Make sure the text-encoding is set to "UTF-8" not `cp1252` or anything else.

Comment: Check whether you have that particular font installed in your system.

Comment: yeah, thanks. It was wrong file encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your character getting saved with encoding `"Cp1252"` so that you are getting the blank.

When you will execute your program you will get the following pop up in eclipse 
[image]